# Cakephp $scaffold doesn't display associated models

Tags: relational-database, cakephp-2.0, scaffold

Help me please, I'm desperate!
I have this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `baskets` (
 id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
 `name` varchar(20) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `apples` (
 id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `basket_id` INT UNSIGNED ,`type` int,  
 FOREIGN KEY (basket_id) references  baskets(id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

These are my models:

```
class Apple extends AppModel {
  public $name = 'Apple';
  public $recursive = 2;
  public $belongsTo = 'Basket';
}

class Basket extends AppModel {
 public $name = 'Basket';
 public $recursive = 2;
 public $hasMany = 'Apple';
}
```

However, when I call the variable $scaffold on either one of them, and try to update or create a new apple; the little drop-down thingy where I would normally choose a basket is empty.

What can I do???? I'm gonna get fired if I don't solve this by monday :(